# Convert 2D Array rows to dictionary in Python

Tags: python, arrays, generator

I have 2D Array. i want to convert the each row as dictionary with value 0 in Python.

Array format is

```
P T P
T P T
T T P
```

used the below Dictionary Comprehensions logic,

```
dic = {y: 0 for y in x}
```

to get output like,

```
{'P': 0, 'T': 0, 'P': 0}
{'T': 0, 'P': 0, 'T': 0}
{'T': 0, 'T': 0, 'P': 0}
```

But i'm getting below output

```
{'P': 0, 'T': 0}
{'T': 0, 'P': 0}
{'T': 0, 'P': 0}
```

Could you help me to solve this.

Comment: `[{j : 0 for j in i} for i in array]`

Comment: Wait is that supposed to be one dictionary or does it come out as 2?

Comment: need to generate dictionary for each row

Comment: Wow.. it is working now. thanks a lot.